# extract an object from from a JSON response in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, websocket

I am receiving a message from a WebSocket like so

```
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
       debugger
       if (e.data.startsWith('MESSAGE'))
           alert(JSON.stringify(e.data))
       ImageReceived(e.data)
       console.log(JSON.stringify(e.data))
   }
```

the message, However, is received correctly, but I am having some difficulties in extracting the content I desire from the message.
The message looks as follows, and I want to extract this part from the message :

```
{"physicalPath":"E:\\NORMAL\\person.jpeg","status":"Normal","version":47,"issuer":"gmail.com","id":32631}
```

and the message is structured as follows

```
"MESSAGE
expires:1607105481567
destination:/queue/f@gil.com
_type:com.model.Image
priority:9
message-id:ID:LA99343812-1:1:1:1:20
persistent:true
timestamp:1607105445567

{"physicalPath":"E:\\NORMAL\\person.jpeg","status":"Normal","version":47,"issuer":"gmail.com","id":32631}"
```

Comment: you could try `var data = e.data.match(/{[^}]*}/)[0];`

Comment: thank you very much, this worked. but it leads to the next question :) .

Comment: how can I extract the individual attribultes, e.g. I want to get only the physicalPath attribute, do you have an idea about how to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your last comment: You could try to parse the extracted string into an actual object

```
var data = JSON.parse(e.data.match(/{[^}]*}/)[0]);
```

alternatively (data is not valid JSON)

```
var data = new Function("", "return " + e.data.match(/{[^}]*}/)[0])()
```

then you can access the individual properties like this

```
data.physicalPath
```

Comment: this returns :1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: maybe because the JSON is not a valid JSON?

Comment: @Fadi Yeah, try the alernative version (I just updated my answer).